# Read data from excel sheet in java with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a data in an excel sheet that I need to read in java, I am able to read normal Strings but when I try to read a cell that contains a date and time (28/5/2018 10:00) I get only the date as 28-May-2018.

This is the excel cell

[image]

This code read: 28-May-2018

[image]

```
row.getCell(6).toString()
```

This code throws an exception:

```
row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue()
```

How can I read the time?

How can I read the date correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
row                              // Starting with a Poi `Row` object.
.getCell(6)                      // Extract a Poi `Cell` object.
.getDateCellValue()              // Extract value from spreadsheet as a `java.util.Date` object. This terrible class is now legacy. Immediately convert to java.time.Instant as seen on next line.
.toInstant()                     // Convert from legacy `java.util.Date` class to modern `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC.
.atZone(                         // Adjusting from UTC to a time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )    // Specify a time zone to adjust from UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). 
)                                // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
.toLocalDate()                   // Extract the date-only portion. Or call `toLocalTime` for the time-of-day portion.
```

## Details

The other Answers correctly show how to get a `java.util.Date` object. But that class is (a) terrible, and (b) now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. You need to go further to get a proper solution.

After getting your `java.util.Date` object:

```
java.util.Date javaUtilDate = row.getCell(6).getDateCellValue() ;
```

…you have a moment in time in UTC. Unfortunately, following the advice to call `Date::toString`:

```
row.getCell(6).getDateCellValue().toString()
```

…creates a confusing the result. That method applies the JVM’s current default time zone, adjusting from UTC to some zone. That creates the illusion that this time zone was part of the `java.util.Date`, but that is not true. And this behavior means your results will vary at runtime depending on whatever the current default time zone might be. Be aware that not only the user can change the default time zone, but so can any code in any thread of any app running within that JVM.

For predictable results, you should specify the desired/expected time zone.

To do so, immediately convert your `java.util.Date` to its replacement, the `Instant` class. Both represent a moment in UTC. Notice the new conversion methods added to the old legacy classes.

```
Instant instant = javaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it explicitly, and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Apply that time zone to your moment in UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId ) ;
```

The resulting [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object represents the same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline as the `Instant`. But its wall-clock time has been adjusted to that used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

You asked:

> How can I read the time?
>
> How can I read the date correctly?

You can use a `DateTimeFormatter` to print either or both in any format you desire, or even automatically localize to the human language and cultural norms defined in a `Locale` object.

Or you can extract the date and time values as separate objects.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime localTime = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Current `apache poi 4.1.1` version provides [java.time.LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getLocalDateTimeCellValue--). And there is [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to get the cell contents as formatted strings using the same formats as in `Excel`.

Comment: Thank you!
your answer was very informative and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
row.getCell(6).getDateCellValue();
```

And if you still need it to be a string, try

```
row.getCell(6).getDateCellValue().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a magic!
just need to parse it in the format that i need.

I can't belive that i didn't saw this function in the documentation when i searched there.

Comment: No problem! Makes sense why you had the exception thrown on the second code block

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Read a cell the first row and sixth cell.
        HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(6);


        // Using HSSFDateUtil to check if a cell contains a date.
        if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            System.out.println("The cell contains a date value: "
                + cell.getDateCellValue());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you,

The function "cell.getDateCellValue()" did the work of what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the cell values as formatted strings as shown in the `Excel` cells, do using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html).

Example:

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
...
Row row = ...;
...
Cell cell = row.getCell(6);
String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
System.out.println(value);
...
```

And because the value might be result of a formula, do using using a `DataFormatter` together with a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html):

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
...
Workbook workbook = ...;
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
...
Row row = ...;
...
Cell cell = row.getCell(6);
String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
System.out.println(value);
...
```